# Is there a virtualbox indicator?

Tags: unity, 11.10, indicator, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

Is there any indicator that compatible with Ubuntu 11.10 with unity?I use it in Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Refer this answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/38057/63025

Answer (score 3):

FYI, I've created a bunch of indicators (including indicator-virtual-box) located at https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Otto didn't package indicator-virtualbox for Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric. I tried adding the PPA for Natty and it unfortunately didn't work. However, I tried downloading the .Deb binary [from here (on Launchpad)](https://launchpad.net/~michael-astrapi/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/1412100/+listing-archive-extra). You can do the following in the terminal:

For 32-bit:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~michael-astrapi/+archive/ppa/+build/2122538/+files/indicator-virtualbox_1.1.1%7Eastrapi%7Enatty1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i './indicator-virtualbox_1.1.1~astrapi~natty1_i386.deb'
```

For 64-bit:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~michael-astrapi/+archive/ppa/+build/2122537/+files/indicator-virtualbox_1.1.1%7Eastrapi%7Enatty1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i './indicator-virtualbox_1.1.1~astrapi~natty1_amd64.deb'
```

Remember, you're doing this at your own risk. I'm simply confirming that it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think any indicator that works in 11.04 should work in 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for Unity indictors:
http://news.softpedia.com/news/Top-10-Ubuntu-11-04-Unity-Panel-Applets-208034.shtml